# How do I reinstall broken python3-pkg-resources?

Tags: python, linux

I have tried `apt-get clean` (also tried auto clean)

The files are still there and it gives me `sub-process /use/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`.

I tried this:

```
sudo dpkg —-configure -a
```

and got error:

```
processing package with -
Python3-pkg-resources (—-configure): package is in a very bad state; you should reinstall before attempting reconfiguration.
Dependency problems for python3-setuptools(depends on python3-pkg-resources)
Dependancy problems prevent configuration of python3-pip:
Depends on -setuptools.
```

So I need to reinstall the -pkg-resources but I don’t know how to delete it.
Edit: it isn't installed but i cant remove the file and I cant download it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
pkg uninstall python3-pkg-resources
pkg install python3-pkg-resources
```

Have you tried this ?